# How to find the bar_index based on a certain time in Pine (Trading View)

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I have a timestamp for a specific day and would like to know what the bar_index is for that bar based on today.  I'm trying to go back 5 days so have figured out the time for it so just need to figure out how many bars back it is from right now so that I can use it a reference for plotting some trendlines.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Aman

Answer (score 0):

```
var int my_index = 0
if time == timestamp(....)
    my_index := bar_index
```

Also a smarter solution would be

```
nb_bars = ta.barssince(time == timestamp(...))
```